# MVC Partial view using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have made an MVC application and I'm trying to create a partial view for when the user clicks the "details" button. I have one partial view working at the moment for my "delete" button. When I step through my code using breakpoints it brings me as far as my Task Controller and steps into my PartialViewResult method but then goes no further. When I click the "details" button nothing happens. Not sure what is missing here.

Index.cshtml

```
       <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="showTask('@item.TaskId')">Details</span>

<div id="Detail"></div>

<Script>
        function showTask(showTaskID) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowTaskByID")',
            data: { id: showTaskID },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Detail').hide();
                $('#Detail').html(data);
                $('#Detail').animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    left: "+=50",
                    height: "toggle"
                }, 3000, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                });

                $('#Edit').hide();
                $('#Delete').hide();
            },
            error: function (data) { $('#Details').html('<h3>Error</h3>'); }
        });
    }



</script>
```

_ShowTask

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.Task>
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size:20px">
        <h2>List of Actors</h2>
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "CreateTask", null, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" })
    </p>
    @if (Model.Any())
    {
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().TaskName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().StartDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().FinishDate)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FinishDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTask", new { id = item.TaskId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
                            @*<a onclick="showEditActor('@item.MovieID','@item.ActorID','@item.ActorName','@item.age')" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>*@
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteTask", new { id = item.TaskId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            } @* closing of if *@
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <div><strong>No Actors in Movie</strong></div>
    }
</div>
```

Task Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var q = db.Tasks.Find(id);
    if (q == null)
    {
    }
    return View(q);
}

public PartialViewResult ShowTaskByID(int id)
{

    return PartialView("_ShowTask", db.Tasks.Find(id).TaskName);
}
```

Comment: Run Fiddler while loading the partial, and see what is returned. Sounds like a client side issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input id="btnDetail" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Details" />

<div id="Detail"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#btnDetail').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '@Url.Action("ShowTaskByID")',
        data: { id: showTaskID },
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#Detail').html(data);
        $('#Detail').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: "+=50",
            height: "toggle"
        }, 3000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });

        $('#Edit').hide();
        $('#Delete').hide();
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('#Detail').html('<h3>Error :' + jqXHR.responseText + '</h3>'); 
    });
});
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    try 
    {
       var task = db.Tasks.Find(id);
    }
    catch(HttpException e) 
    {
       throw new HttpException(404, "Task not found.")
    }

    return View(task);
}

public PartialViewResult ShowTaskByID(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var tasks = db.Tasks.Find(id).TaskName;    
    }
    catch(HttpException e) 
    {
       throw new HttpException(404, "Task nout found.")
    }

    return PartialView("_ShowTask", tasks);
}
```

If you are expecting a list of Tasks try this:

```
public PartialViewResult ShowTaskByID()
{
    try
    {
        var tasks = db.Tasks.ToList();
    }
    catch(HttpException e) 
    {
       throw new HttpException(404, "Task nout found.")
    }

    return PartialView("_ShowTask", tasks);
}
```

Or instead, you could edit _ShowTask model type to Task:

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.Task

<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="font-size:20px">
        <h2>List of Actors</h2>
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "CreateTask", null, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" })
    </p>
    @if (Model.Any())
    {
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaskName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FinishDate)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FinishDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTask", new { id = Model.TaskId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
                        @*<a onclick="showEditActor('@item.MovieID','@item.ActorID','@item.ActorName','@item.age')" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>*@
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteTask", new { id = Model.TaskId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
            } @* closing of if *@
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <div><strong>No Actors in Movie</strong></div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I got the fallowing error when using your code snippet. Any ideas on how I would fix this. `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Task_E325CAFED3402B9E516E7467C55ACD948A2123A1FE7EECA32D7824C88DD807C4', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication4.Models.Task]'.`

Comment: _ShowTask is expecting IEnumerable<WebApplication4.Models.Task>, looks like you are passing an object and not an IEnumerable. I'll update the code above.

Comment: I added the code and got the fallowing error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication4.Models.Task]'.`

Comment: I got it working using your code I left something out. Thanks for your help and I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

[HttpGet]
add the tag to your `public PartialViewResult ShowTaskByID(int id)`

so, it should result like:

`[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ShowTaskByID(int id)`